# How to apply styles to label tag?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have radio buttons which is something like this-

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle custom-btns" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" [(ngModel)]="model">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="middle"> Middle
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
  </label>
</div>
```

Now if I'm trying to use the active or focus property on the btn-primary class, it's not working. The only thing I see is the default chrome outline when a button is selected.  Here is the CSS I'm using-

```
.custom-btns{
    .btn-primary:hover{
        background-color: green;
        color: black;
    }
    .btn-primary:focus, btn-primary:active{
        color: #fff ;
        background: blue;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
}
```

I want the label to turn green when I hover over it and blue when it is focused.
Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. You just tell us it doesn't work, but don't really tell us what you are trying to do. I think maybe you could try to use `:focus-within` instead of `:focus`, which will apply the "focus" styles to the label when then input inside the label has focus

Comment: focus-within worked for me. Thanks!